# My Car Wont Turn over Need Help!

Tags: engine, electrical, battery, starting, manual-transmission

So i have a 1999 mitsubishi eclipse 2.0L manual transmission and it's not turning over at all. It just clicks. I changed the starter nothing and its still clicks the battery is good the altinater good as well. Can someone please help im completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your earth connections are bad, undo all the earth straps and sand the connections with fine emery paper, re connect and all should be good